# Remove some text content from HTML div and remove remaining text without failing style

Tags: javascript, dom

I wanted to remove characters of text from html and show the rest without failing style

If the number of characters is 20,

I have :

```
<p>
     <span class="text-huge">TE</span>
     <span class="text-huge" style="color:hsl(0, 75%, 60%);">ST</span>
     <span class="text-small" style="color:hsl(0, 75%, 60%);">ing&nbsp;</span>
</p>
<p>
      <span class="text-small" style="color:hsl(0, 75%, 60%);">SEn</span>
      <span class="text-huge">&nbsp;</span>
</p>
<p>
      <span class="text-huge">Keep some text and remove remaining with number of charectors</span>
</p>
```

And I wanted :

```
<p>
     <span class="text-huge">TE</span>  <span class="text-huge" style="color:hsl(0, 75%, 60%);">ST</span>
     <span class="text-small" style="color:hsl(0, 75%, 60%);">ing&nbsp;</span>
</p>
<p>
      <span class="text-small" style="color:hsl(0, 75%, 60%);">SEn</span>
      <span class="text-huge">&nbsp;</span>
</p>
<p>
      <span class="text-huge">Keep som</span>
</p>
```

Actually my requirement is to remove some characters based on n(no. of characters to display) in a sentence in which some styles are applied, those styles should not remove

Answer (score 0):

If I undestand you correctly, you want to shorten a text in span if it is longer than N characters:

```
<span id="span" class="text-huge">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
```

Note: this will only work if span contains only plain text NOT HTML

```
function checkLength(n) {
    const span = document.getElementById("span");
    const html = span.innerHTML;

    if(html.length > n) {
        span.innerHTML = html.slice(0, n);
    }
}
```